# Randomly select one of last 3 posts

Tags: wp-query, order, sql

ok so i have this:

```
    $args=array(
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'order'    => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'offset' => $offset,
    );
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if ($q->have_posts()) {}
```

what im looking for is to Randomly show one of the last 3 posts:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 3) 
AS temptable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If you know your MYSQL queries, you could just use them with $wbdb. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb. Other wise you will need to query the first 3 posts first and then maybe put them in a array and sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$args=array(
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'order'    => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'offset' => $offset,
    );
$q = new WP_Query($args);


if($q->post_count>0){
    $random_post = $q->posts[mt_rand(0,2)];
}
```

also, just a little note, ORDER BY RAND() is pretty bad for performance

Comment: *"...ORDER BY RAND() is pretty bad for performance"* - can you please pose a link to support your argument?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam honestly, I can't support my point personally. I haven't done any benchmark regarding this. When I studied MYSQL and I heard a lot of negative opinions towards that. What I can provide to you is googling "order by rand mysql performance".